# Java Maven Project with certificate problem on command line

Tags: java, maven, ssl

I have a Java Maven project which I develop in Eclipse IDE. In this project I use Sardine to make a webdav connection to a HTTPS URL (API).
In eclipse I can run the project by main method as Java application without problems, it connects to the API and works without exceptions.
When I make a "mvn package" and try to execute the JAR File on command line (on Windows 10) it throws a

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I have already added the certificate of the API URL to my cacerts by keytool, but it didn't help.
I am using same Java 17 version for both executions.

Does someone have an idea what is going wrong? What is eclipse doing different than command line is doing?

Thx for your help!

Greets
Forfaro

Comment: *I am using same Java 17 version for both executions.* I suspect that you are *not* ;) `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` as the first line of your entry point

Comment: On windows: `where java` (first result), on linux `which java` will provide the path from which you are executing java. Are you sure it is the path inside which you have added the certificate to trust? There could even be a case where you have installed java17 in two places.

Comment: *... will provide the path from which you are executing java* Not necessarily at all. IDEs generally have their own configurations which can bear little to no relation to environment paths. The above method I suggested will remove all doubt